# How to improve reducer updating deep state object

Tags: reactjs, redux, merge

I have a reducer with update action, works fine but i want to know if there is an way for improve the code.

The store data is like:

```
{
  test1: {
    name: 'test1',
    exercises: [
      {
        category: 'Hombro',
        name: 'Prensa de hombros',
        type: 'Peso y repeticiones',
        data: {
          weight: 10,
          reps: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        category: 'Hombro',
        name: 'Prensa de hombros con respaldo',
        type: 'Peso y repeticiones',
        data: {
          weight: 10,
          reps: 3,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  test2: {
    name: 'test2',
    exercises: [],
  },
}
```

An the strategy for update, for example, the data property of a single exercise is like:

```
const updateExerciseDataOfRoutine = (state, action) => {
  const { routineName, exerciseName, data } = action.payload

  return {
    ...state.routines,
    [routineName]: {
      ...state.routines[routineName],
      exercises: {
        ...state.routines[routineName].exercises,
        [exerciseName]: {
          ...state.routines[routineName].exercises[exerciseName],
          data,
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const RoutinesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
if (action.type === DO_UPDATE_EXERCISE_DATA_OF_ROUTINE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      routines: updateExerciseDataOfRoutine(state, action),
    }
  }

  return state
}
```

In the reducer the logic is do a merge over merge over merge. This is for don't lose the rest of the object data.

I think i can do a function for iterate over object until find the property to update, but i want to know if you manage this type of situations with other way.

Comment: I would recommend https://github.com/aearly/icepick

Comment: The algorithm is correct and there is basically no way to improve over that unless you use a library specifically designed to make deep updates on immutables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Redux docs article on "Immutable Update Patterns"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns), that approach is correct.

If doing that by hand is a pain, we recommend using the [`immer` immutable update library](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer/).  Also, our new [`redux-starter-kit` package](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-starter-kit) uses immer internally to let you write reducers with simpler immutable update logic.  I'd encourage you to try it out.